# Distinct subjects, Sum and group by

Tags: mysql

i have a situation with a table like this:

```
----------------------------------------------
|   id   |  subject |    type    |   value   |
==============================================
|   1    |  AAA     |     IN     |   900.00  |
|   2    |  BBB     |     IN     |   200.00  | 
|   3    |  BBB     |     OUT    |   140.00  | 
|   4    |  AAA     |     OUT    |   650.00  | 
|   5    |  BBB     |     IN     |    90.00  | 
|   6    |  CCC     |     OUT    |   50.80   | 
|   7    |  AAA     |     OUT    |   480.40  | 
|   8    |  CCC     |     IN     |   645.20  |
|   9    |  CCC     |     OUT    |   111.80  |
|--------|----------|------------|-----------|
```

and i need to sum all values based on their type and show the results for each subject so the desired result must be:

```
----------------------------------------
|  subject | income(IN) | outcome(OUT) |
========================================
|  AAA     |   900.00   |    1130.40   |
|  BBB     |   290.00   |     140.00   |
|  CCC     |   645.20   |     162.60   |
```

where the income(IN) column shows the sums of each subject where type is IN and the same does the column: outcome(OUT).
I have try several query but without success.

Would be nice your help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use conditional aggregation using [`Case..When`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/control-flow-functions.html#operator_case) expression with `Group By` clause:

```
SELECT
  subject, 
  SUM(CASE WHEN type = 'IN' THEN value END) AS income, 
  SUM(CASE WHEN type = 'OUT' THEN value END) AS outcome 
FROM your_table 
GROUP BY subject
```

**EDIT:**

It seems from [comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53145081/distinct-subjects-sum-and-group-by/53145094?noredirect=1#comment93181666_53145094) that datatype of the `value` column is not numeric. It is string, with possible commas in it (due to number formatting). We will need to use [`Replace()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_replace) function to replace the commas with empty string. And, then use [`Cast()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/cast-functions.html#function_cast) to convert it into numeric value.

```
SELECT
  subject, 
  SUM(CASE WHEN type = 'IN' 
           THEN CAST(REPLACE(value, ',', '') AS DECIMAL(11,2)) 
      END) AS income, 
  SUM(CASE WHEN type = 'OUT' 
           THEN CAST(REPLACE(value, ',', '') AS DECIMAL(11,2)) 
      END) AS outcome 
FROM your_table 
GROUP BY subject
```

Comment: in the outcome the type must be OUT ?? because values dont match

Comment: Yes thanks, i ask for being sure. Please another improvment. as my values are in the format: 1,234.00 normally i use FORMAT(SUM(REPLACE(value, ',', '')), 2) to have the correct sum either it stops on the first number because dont recognize comma, how can i use format on SUM(CASE...)? thanks again

Comment: @Sigma what is the datatype of `value` column. Is it not numeric type ?

Comment: @Sigma also I would recommend you to do all sorts of formatting for display purposes in your application code (eg: PHP).

Comment: No it isnt, because from jquery format i need data to be in 1,234.00 format. its a varchar but validation is maded on client side before data are inserted on db

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/183091/discussion-between-sigma-and-madhur-bhaiya).